# How does the heatmap function in R cluster the data an how can we get the number of groups?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, heatmap

I have a distance matrix which is plotted with `heatmap` function. The heatmap function cluster the data  to the groups. I want to cluster them to the same group.

The arguments are:

```
heatmap(distanceMatrix, symm = T)
```

The groups of data is evident in the diagnal of matrix.

something like this:

[image]

In fact I  looking for the number of groups. After that I can use `hcluste` and `cut` in R to partition the data.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the help file of the function (`?heatmap)? See the below arguments.

```
distfun 
function used to compute the distance (dissimilarity) between both rows and columns. Defaults to dist.

hclustfun   
function used to compute the hierarchical clustering when Rowv or Colv are not dendrograms. Defaults to hclust. Should take as argument a result of distfun and return an object to which as.dendrogram can be applied.
```

Comment: Thanks, I am looking for the number of groups. edited.

Answer (score 0):

The`library(NbClust)` package solved the problem

"NbClust: An examination of indices for determining the number of clusters : NbClust Package"